# TYPO3 News system, how to show Archive list

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Im running TYPO3 v. 6.1, FLUID/EXTBASE.

I have installed the Extension News System and it's working fine.

Now im trying to show an archive list, but im not getting any list.
I have added my code to a lib. so it's a lib im calling on my main page.

Can someone see whats wrong in this code.

```
lib.NewsArchive < plugin.tt_news 
lib.NewsArchive { 
  datetimeDaysToArchive = {$plugin.tt_news.datetimeDaysToArchive}
  enableArchiveDate = 1
  pageTypoLink.parameter.current = 1

  reverseAMenu = 1
  archiveMenuNoEmpty = 1

  # the Condition in the following COA highlights the active Archive month
  archiveTitleCObject = COA
  archiveTitleCObject {
    10 = TEXT
    10 {
       field = start
       strftime = %B %Y
       wrap = <strong>|</strong>
       if {
          value.field = start
          equals.data = GPvar:tx_ttnews|pS
        }
     }
    20 = TEXT
    20 {
       field = start
       strftime = %B %Y
       if {
          value.field = start
          equals.data = GPvar:tx_ttnews|pS
          negate = 1
        }
     }
  }
  archiveEmptyMsg_stdWrap.wrap =
  searchEmptyMsg_stdWrap.wrap =
  noNewsIdMsg_stdWrap.wrap =
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it with the Frontend Plugin version?  Could be that your combination of datetimeDaysToArchive/enableArchiveDate does result in an empty list.  I vaguely recall that I had to explicitily set the "Archive date" value on a tt_news news item to have it shown in the archive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing up two different Extensions.

You are working with News System, but your TypoScript belongs to tt_news.

http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/news
http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/tt_news