# TYPO3 tx_news archive list

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, tx-news

I want to want to show a list of archived Events sorted by years.

2017

- Event 1
- Event 2
- ...

2016

- Event 1
- Event 2
- ...

In the old tt_news there were predefined objects like "datetimeDaysToArchive" and [more](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/tt_news/Manual/Index.html?highlight=archivetitlecobject#archive-settings). They seem to be disappeared in tx_news . Is there a similar way in **tx_news** to show a List of archived Events sorted by years? Maybe with a Date menu?

I found a similar question, but for tt_news [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20187588/typo3-news-system-how-to-show-archive-list/50476878#50476878)
(I`m working on TYPO3 v. 8.7.13, tx_news v. 7.0.4)

Thanks in advance Markus

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to comment Georgs answer, but lacked the necessary reputation to do so.

You can set `tx_news.predefine.archive = 30 days` in the pageTS. New records then have the archive date prefilled with a date 30 days in the future. Other values like `next year` or `tomorrow` work as well.

Answer (score 0):

EXT:news has got the mode "Date menu" - see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/drafts/github/georgringer/news/UsersManual/Plugins/Index.html#date-menu. This can be used to build date menus just as you need. Define to show only archived news and you are done.

The setting `datetimeDaysToArchive` does not exist in news, you need to set a real archive date. You can of course set it also in a cron job or preset the archive date with something like this: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/drafts/github/georgringer/news/AdministratorManual/Configuration/TsConfig/Index.html#archive

Comment: Thank you. That  was extactly the requested answer. My archive works now fine.